# Regex matching positive or negative dollar amount or percentage

Tags: javascript, regex

How might I efficiently use regex to match input that could be a positive or negative dollar amount or percentage.

- Input could start with optional + or -
- Followed by optional $
- Then digits with optional comma as a digit group separator following a digit in the thousands/hundred thousands/millions...
- Followed by an optional decimal point and one or two digits
- And finally a possible %, but only if the input doesn't contain a $, and the number is from -100.00 to +100.00

So it would match input like:
12, -60, $25.50, -$1.5, +$25,000, 5.5%, -100%, +100%, 0.01%

And return false with input like:
Text, +$10%, -5.001

I've been evaluating them separately with:

```
function percentValue(input) {
    regex = /^[+-]?\$?(?=.)(\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)?(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
    return regex.test(input);
}

function dollarValue(input) {
    regex = /^[+-]? *100(\.0{0,2})? *%?$|^[+-]? *\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})? *%?$/;
    return regex.test(input);
}
```

Results

```
percentValue('5.5%');  // True
percentValue('-100%'); // True
percentValue('+.01%'); // True
percentValue('0.001'); // False
percentValue('101%');  // False
percentValue('$100%'); // False

dollarValue('+$12');    // True
dollarValue('-$60.5');  // True
dollarValue('$25,000'); // True
dollarValue('-$5.001'); // False
dollarValue('1,00.25'); // False
dollarValue('$text');   // False
```

I've been unsuccessful trying to combine them into one. Should I be using another lookahead for the percentage?

Comment: Use two regular expressions, one for dollar amount, another for percentage. You can then combine them with `|` to match either type.

Comment: I would advise using two separate regular expressions as Barmar stated above. You can do one if statement that checks for the dollar sign regex followed by one if statement that checks for the percentage regex. It doesn't have to be all done in one regex. I would advise using regexstorm.net/reference to see examples and then use regexstorm.net/tester to test. You just play around with the regex until it's matching what you want.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks, edited to add code, appreciate the kindness.

Comment: @MarkS @Barmar Thanks for the pointer.  I was thinking of a more complicated solution.  Used

`let regex = /^[+-]?\$?(?=.)(\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)?(\.\d{1,2})?$|^[+-]? *100(\.0{0,2})? *%?$|^[+-]? *\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})? *%?$/;`

with a simple OR and it works great.

Comment: Just combine them with `|`: `/^[+-]?\$?(?=.)(\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)?(\.\d{1,2})?$|^[+-]? *100(\.0{0,2})? *%?$|^[+-]? *\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})? *%?$/`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = [
    '12',
    '-60',
    '$25.50',
    '-$1.5',
    '+$25,000',
    '5.5%',
    '-100%',
    '+100%',
    '0.01%',
    'Text',
    '+$10%',
    '-5.001',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^[+-]?(?:\$?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d?)?|(?:100|\d\d?)(?:\.\d\d?)?%)$/.test(a);
}));
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Kjc1ZD/1)

Comment: `"0.01% :true"` shouldn't match

Comment: also making a more readable/clean code solution would be more beneficial to everyone

Comment: @Leonardo: `0.01%` **must** match, (re)read the question: “So it would match input like: `12, -60, $25.50, -$1.5, +$25,000, 5.5%, -100%, +100%, 0.01%`”